# Keyboard not working after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: keyboard, troubleshooting, windows-10, windows-10-upgrade

I have a lenovo z500 series laptop..  I've been using windows 8.1 up until now and my keyboard worked fine no problem but today i upgraded to Windows 10 my keyboard ua not working now...

I checked the device manager and it has the keyboard  installed..  It shows standard ps/2 keyboard  installed and working  properly in device manager...  But it is not actually working..  None of the keys seems to respond..

Any help regarding this matter..

Answer (score 1):

I also have a Lenovo laptop and after the upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, my touchpad and keyboard also stopped working. But after I rebooted the computer multiple times they both worked again.

Answer (score 1):

Also not working for me on my Z500, It seems to be an issue to do with the Intel Chipset Drivers. On my system I've had to turn off automatic driver download because it breaks -everything-..

A (temporary) solution that works for me is to litterally go into device manager on the laptop, and uninstall the chipset controller, then restart. Hey presto, keyboard works again.

Why the solution is temporary? When you restart again, the keyboard stops working again \o/ huzzah.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with my Lenova Yoga 13.  When I rebooted, it worked fine.  Or if force it to go sleep and the wake it up.

I have had win10 only installed for a week or so.  But what is interesting  is that it seems to automatically go into tablet mode where it is expecting me to use touch interface only.  Once out of tablet mode, seems to work as normal.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a Dell 11 1347. There was no keyboard after updating to windows 10 and the device manager registered no issues with the driver. The problem was fixed by updating the chipset driver.